# Is dead in a reported speech

Tags: grammaticality, reported-speech

Here is a real case I have met in my workplace.

> Staff A: Is the goddamn pigeon dead?
>
> Manager: What's happened? (turn to me)
>
> Me: ...Staff A asked me to check if the annoying pigeon is dead.

I am not sure whether it is grammatically correct to use present tense in the above reported speech, becasue some English teacher said this:

> But, if the reporting verb is in the past tense, then usually we
>   change the tenses in the reported speech.

http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/reported-speech.html

Should I say this instead?

> Staff A asked me to check if the annoying pigeon had been dead.

Comment: It's grammatically correct. There is no reason to use the _past perfect_ unless you are asking about the state of the pigeon in the past. Use the simple present.

Comment: At the very most, you would say "Staff A asked me to check if the annoying pigeon **was** dead."... there's no reason to use "had been". Regardless, unless the pigeon has the ability to come back from the dead, it is **still** dead, so present tense makes total sense.

Comment: You could also say, _"...asked me to check if the annoying pigeon **had died**."_

Comment: @Catija Perhaps the manager's name is Schrödinger.

Comment: Just to clarify: your version "had been dead" is definitely wrong. (But "is dead" and "was dead" are both OK here.)

Comment: I don't think this is reported speech. By deviating from his exact words, you are restating what the manager said. That is, you are stating what the manager said in a different way than he said it. This is not the same as reported speech--especially when you are restating what the manager says so soon after he says it. **Nevertheless, there is no need to go from the present to the past perfect; where do you see that anywhere on the page you link to?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[the pigeon] has been dead" means, the pigeon has experienced death, and by implication, is now alive -- not ungrammatical, but odd sounding, and not the meaning that you intended.

Instead just **use simple present** "... is dead": The state of the pigeon is unchanging through the present and into the future. Unchanging states often use the simple present.

Alternatives:  "... was dead" - Allowed, understood as a casting into the past tense for reported speech. More likely if reporting speech that hadn't just occurred. "Yesterday Jack asked if the pigeon was dead..."

"had died" since "to be dead" means the same as "to have died". Since the death would have occurred before the speech, the past perfect is appropriate.

[Been thinking about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218 ]